# XSLT transform doesn't access nodes (their attributes) without text content in Islandora MODS to DC transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, drupal, islandora

I'm working in Islandora (Drupal) to transform some metadata (MODS to Dublin Core DC) and using XSLT transformation on XML.

The XML looks like this:

```
<mods:mods>
    <mods:extension>
        <mads:madsCollection>
            <mads:mads>
                ...
                <mads:topic lang="hrv" valueURI="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D000349">Afrika</mads:topic>
                <mads:topic lang="eng">Africa</mads:topic>
                ...
            </mads:mads>
            <mads:mads>
                ...
                <mads:topic lang="hrv" valueURI="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D005060">Europa</mads:topic>
                <mads:topic lang="eng">Europe</mads:topic>
                ...
            </mads:mads>
            <mads:mads>
                ...
                <mads:topic lang="hrv" valueURI="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D001208" />
                <mads:topic lang="eng">Asia</mads:topic>
                ...
            </mads:mads>
            <mads:mads>
                ...
            <mads:topic lang="hrv" valueURI="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D001315">Australia</mads:topic>
            <mads:topic lang="eng"/>
                ...
            </mads:mads>
        </mads:madsCollection>
    </mods:extension>
</mods:mods>
```

and XSLT to transform it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" exclude-result-prefixes="mods"
                xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                xmlns:mads="http://www.loc.gov/mads/v2"
                xmlns:srw_dc="info:srw/schema/1/dc-schema"
                xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- WS: updated schema location -->
        <xsl:for-each select="mods:mods">
            <oai_dc:dc xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </oai_dc:dc>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/mods:mods/mods:extension/mads:madsCollection">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mads:mads/mads:topic" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mads:mads/mads:topic">
        <dc:subject>
            <xsl:attribute name="xml:lang">
                <xsl:value-of select="@lang" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@valueURI" />
        </dc:subject>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is this:

```
<oai_dc:dc xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D000349</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="eng"/>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D005060</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="eng"/>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="eng"/>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D001315</dc:subject>
</oai_dc:dc>
```

So as you can see, elements without any text content in them (empty elements) are not read by the XSLT.
The third element doesn't have content in the first `[@lang='hrv']` `mads:topic`, and it doesn't get into output, but I need that `[@valueURI]` in the output.
The fourth element doesn't have content in the second `[@lang='eng']` `mads:topic`, and it doesn't get into output.

Even if it doesn't have any text content in it, I need to get their attributes `[@valueURI]` to DC in element `dc:subject` as text, if that attribute exists.
That's not a problem to test if transformation accesses those nodes, but it obviously doesn't.

So basically I need some output like this:

```
<oai_dc:dc xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D000349</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D005060</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D001208</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D001315</dc:subject>
</oai_dc:dc>
```

Why is this one missing?

```
<dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D001208</dc:subject>
```

Comment: Is your question showing the exact XML you are having problems with? Your XSLT is looking for a root element called `mods` (in the `mods` namespace) but this is not present in your XML.

Comment: well, there is mods:mods as root, and namespace for extension is mods too. XML is shrinked down to problematic part, and XSLT is full and complete!

Comment: I don't think there is problem in other part of XML, as this XSLT access normally siblings and outputs them ok. Problem is in access to this siblings that do not have text content

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tested your XSLT with your XML and the result was quite OK. However, to perfect the result one modification was necessary:

To choose only the elements that contain a `valueURI` attribute a predicate has to be added.

```
<xsl:template match="/mods:mods/mods:extension/mads:madsCollection">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="mads:mads/mads:topic[@valueURI]" />
</xsl:template>
```

The result after applying this modification is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><oai_dc:dc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:mads="http://www.loc.gov/mads/v2" xmlns:srw_dc="info:srw/schema/1/dc-schema" xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">

    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D000349 </dc:subject>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D005060 </dc:subject>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D001208 </dc:subject>
    <dc:subject xml:lang="hrv">http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D001315 </dc:subject>
</oai_dc:dc>
```

P.S.: I just put your input XML into an XSLT processor. The output was as you desired. There was no element missing in the output!

Comment: I'm suspecting that Islandora kills those elements in one of their modules before my transformation, but don't know exactly where

Comment: I'm sorry to read that. I don't know `Islandora` or its institutions or organizations applying it. My answer merely confirms that your input XML is correctly processed by a standard-conform XSLT processor(in my case SaxonB). If _your XSLT processor_ gives a different result, then maybe it's buggy, because Saxon is pretty much the standard.